# Blanche-Neige in “Lily” lyrics

Tags: argot, paroles-de-chanson

What do [these lyrics](http://www.nomorelyrics.net/fr/Pierre_Perret/Lily-paroles.html) mean:

> Et quand on l'appelait Blanche-Neige Lily
>   Elle se laissait plus prendre au piège Lily
>   Elle trouvait ça très amusant
>   Même s’il fallait serrer les dents
>   Ils auraient été trop contents

What does “Blanche-Neige” imply? I don't understand what Perret meant here.

Answer (score 17):

*[Blanche-Neige](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Blanche-Neige)* is the name of *[Snow White](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Snow_White)* in French (it's a literal translation, too).

In this context, considering Lily is black, it's used as a [racist](http://www.djamsession.com/tag/Racisme%20Maghreb) [insult](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article177). It's used towards black women and men indifferently.